# Make mouse wheel behave like arrow keys for camera movement in RTS game

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, gaming

I want my mouse wheel to work like the arrow keys on the keyboard, to move the camera in a game the same way I can do it with wheel left/right, which I could bind via the mouse software. But I could not bind wheel up/down in it.

I came up with this for Autohotkey:

```
wheelup::
Send, {up down}
Sleep, 180
SendInput, {up up}
return

wheeldown::
Send, {down down}
Sleep, 180
SendInput, {down up}
return
```

It kinda works, but the output is not continuous and I want it to be smooth and fluid. There is a delay everytime I make an input on mouse wheel up/down, which I can't get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try any of the solution kindly make sure that the option of “Mouse Keys” is disabled in Ease of Access in Settings. These settings are present in Windows to facilitate the user who doesn’t have a mouse or their mouse is not working properly. Although this option is usually disabled by default but can be enabled by mistake. To check this, follow the steps:

1. Press Windows + R, type “Mouse keys” in the dialogue box and open the setting of
   ‘Turn Mouse keys on or off’.
2. Now, uncheck the option of Control your mouse with a keypad. Save changes and
   exit then restart your computer and see if the issue is resolved.
3. Instead of installing any third party application you can check your CPS by going
   to the website https://cpstest.pro/. Hope this helps!